# Retrieve strings from real time database in a 2D ArrayList Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database structure like this :

[image: Firebase Structure]

How do I retrieve it into a 2D ArrayList like this using Java.

```
private String mChoices [][] = {
        {"Mutare", "Harare", "Bulawayo","Mozambique"},
        {"Johhannesburg", "Pretoria", "Duran","Capetown"},
        {"Nairobi", "Lusaka", "Windhoek","Lilongwe"},
        {"Harare", "Lilongwe", "Pretoria","Nairobi"}
};
```

Comment: Are you sure they you're receiving the data in alphabetically order? As I know firebase by default sends data in the order they are already exists in the database.

Comment: I noticed the error i had put, i changed the question

Comment: The first array should be `Mutare, Harare, Bulawayo, Mozambique` all children of the first node or `Mutare, Johannesburg, Nairobi, Harare`, each element at a specific index? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i have edited the question for clarity, please check and help

Comment: @TinovimbaMawoyo Oh, ti's more clear now. One more question. The number of arrays and the number of elements within the arrays will always be 4 and 4?

Comment: @AlexMamo the columns will always be 4 but the rows can be a thousand

Comment: @TinovimbaMawoyo I see, I'll write you an answer right away, using arrays.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks will be waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SardorbekKhujaev mentioned in his answer, the arrays are fixed data-types. To solve the problem, we need to use an ArrayList, as the size can be increased dynamically. Once we populate the ArrayList we can simply convert it into an 2D array, like in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference choicesRef = rootRef.child("choices");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String[]> choices = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int size = (int) ds.getChildrenCount();
            String[] choice = new String[size];
            int count = 0;
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
                choice[count++] = dSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            }
            choices.add(choice);
        }
        String choicesArray[][] = new String[choices.size()][];
        for (int j = 0; j < choices.size(); j++) {
            choicesArray[j] = choices.get(j);
        }
        //Test the array
        for(String[] array : choicesArray) {
            Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(array));
        }
        //Do what you need to do with your 2D array
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
choicesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result of this code will be the exact 2D array that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to work with a 2D array, which makes the code more complex, as arrays are not dynamic. Taking into account that firebase data is dynamic and the general convenience of array lists in Java, I recommend you to use ArrayList.
This solution focuses on the matter of the question - a 2D array

```
private String[][] mChoices;
private void initializeMChoices(int i, int j) {
    mChoices = new String[i][j];
}
```

Wherever you need to fill the array with the String values, paste this code:

```
        //Get the reference to the "choices" node:
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("choices");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // We first go through the whole node to count it's child nodes
                int i = 0, j = 0;
                while(snapshot.child(Integer.toString(i)).exists())
                {
                    j = 0;
                    while(snapshot.child(Integer.toString(i)).child(Integer.toString(i)).exists())
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                // we have the numbers, now we initialize the array
                initializeMChoices(i, j);
            //we go through the whole node to put child-node values in the 2D array
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            while(snapshot.child(Integer.toString(i)).exists())
            {
                while(snapshot.child(Integer.toString(i)).child(Integer.toString(i)).exists())
                {
                    j++;
                    mChoices[i][j] = snapshot.child(Integer.toString(i)).child(Integer.toString(i)).toString();
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: How do i use arrayLists, i think they are the perfect ones

Comment: @AlexMamo provided a code snippet implementing ArrayLists. I think now your problem is solved and both my and Alex's answers can be considered correct. I see Alex paraphrased the question half an hour ago for it to be generally useful.